# How to declare a variable in mysql and how to create a CURSOR

Tags: mysql, cursor, declare

I am creating a CURSOR in mysql (*version is 5.0.96-community*), but it is alerting me an error with  my variable declaration.

Even when I cut it down and is left with only one sentence declared, it still shows error.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615193/mysql-cursor-creating-a-procedure?rq=1

Comment: Could you please re-check my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try like this,

```
delimiter $$
create procedure curdemo()
begin
declare a char(16);
end ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> > > > > > > > Declare values like [ INT or Longtext and text ]

```
DECLARE i INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_current_item LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE v_emp_json TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
```

> > > > > > > > Decalre values