# Can you pass multiple rows of selected data into a procedure singularly in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, into-outfile

Currently I have two procedures, one that passes the names of the tables into another procedure that will use the names to preform other tasks.

What I have:
Used to pass table names to other function.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Save()
BEGIN
CALL OTHERPROCEDURE('Tablename1');
CALL OTHERPROCEDURE('Tablename2');
CALL OTHERPROCEDURE('Tablename3');
//etc...
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The issue I have is that at the moment I have only a few tables, which I can manually write in as shown above. However as more tables get introduced this becomes unpractical.

`select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'testdb';`

So my idea was to use this select function that will return the names of all tables int he database *testdb*, then these name will then be passed into the procedure *OTHERPROCEDURE* one at a time. Although I know there are ways of doing this using the likes of PHP but I am trying to have it work solely with MySQL, if possible.

Is this even possible? If so how?

Comment: The thing you are looking for is a [cursor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4615193/6248528) a random example.

Comment: That exactly what I was looking for, thanks.